# Find function for data

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on an integer factorization problem, and I need to find a function for my data. I have tried several polynomial functions, but they did not work. I know that there are infinitely many functions of this kind. But for my purposes I just want to understand what kind of function it is. Please help me figure it out.

Data

```
1 1 
2 1 
3 1 
4 1 
5 1 
6 1 
7 2 
8 2 
9 2 
10 2 
11 2 
12 2 
13 3 
14 3 
15 3 
16 3 
17 3 
18 3 
19 3 
20 4 
21 4 
22 4 
23 4 
24 4 
25 4 
26 5 
27 5 
28 5 
29 5 
30 5 
31 5 
32 6 
33 6 
34 6 
35 6 
36 6 
37 6 
38 7 
39 7 
40 7 
41 7 
42 7 
43 7 
44 8 
45 8 
46 8 
47 8 
48 8 
49 8 
50 9 
51 9 
52 9 
53 9 
54 9 
55 9 
56 10 
57 10 
58 10 
59 10 
60 10 
61 10 
62 11 
63 11 
64 11 
65 11 
66 11 
67 11 
68 12 
69 12 
70 12 
71 12 
72 12 
73 12 
74 13 
75 13 
76 13 
77 13 
78 13 
79 13 
80 14 
81 14 
82 14 
83 14 
84 14 
85 14 
86 15 
87 15 
88 15 
89 15 
90 15 
91 15 
92 16 
93 16 
94 16 
95 16 
96 16 
97 17 
98 17 
99 17 
100 17 
101 17 
102 17 
103 18 
104 18 
105 18 
106 18 
107 18 
108 18 
109 19 
110 19 
111 19 
112 19 
113 19 
114 20 
115 20 
116 20 
117 20 
118 20 
119 20 
120 21 
121 21 
122 21 
123 21 
124 21 
125 21 
126 22 
127 22 
128 22 
129 22 
130 22 
131 23 
132 23 
133 23 
134 23 
135 23 
136 23 
137 24 
138 24 
139 24 
140 24 
141 24 
142 25 
143 25 
144 25 
145 25 
146 25 
147 25 
148 26 
149 26 
150 26 
151 26 
152 26 
153 27 
154 27 
155 27 
156 27 
157 27 
158 27 
159 28 
160 28 
161 28 
162 28 
163 28 
164 29 
165 29 
166 29 
167 29 
168 29 
169 30 
170 30 
171 30 
172 30 
173 30 
174 30 
175 31 
176 31 
177 31 
178 31 
179 31 
180 32 
181 32 
182 32 
183 32 
184 32 
185 33 
186 33 
187 33 
188 33 
189 33 
190 33 
191 34 
192 34 
193 34 
194 34 
195 34 
196 35 
197 35 
198 35 
199 35 
200 35 
201 36 
202 36 
203 36 
204 36 
205 36 
206 37 
207 37 
208 37 
209 37 
210 37 
211 38 
212 38 
213 38 
214 38 
215 38 
216 39 
217 39 
218 39 
219 39 
220 39 
221 40 
222 40 
223 40 
224 40 
225 40 
226 41 
227 41 
228 41 
229 41 
230 41 
231 42 
232 42 
233 42 
234 42 
235 42 
236 43 
237 43 
238 43 
239 43 
240 43 
241 44 
242 44 
243 44 
244 44 
245 44 
246 45 
247 45 
248 45 
249 45 
250 45 
251 46 
252 46 
253 46 
254 46 
255 46 
256 47 
257 47 
258 47 
259 47 
260 47 
261 48 
262 48 
263 48 
264 48 
265 48 
266 49 
267 49 
268 49 
269 49 
270 50 
271 50 
272 50 
273 50 
274 50 
275 51 
276 51 
277 51 
278 51 
279 51 
280 52 
281 52 
282 52 
283 52 
284 52 
285 53 
286 53 
287 53 
288 53 
289 54 
290 54 
291 54 
292 54 
293 54 
294 55 
295 55 
296 55 
297 55 
298 55 
299 56 
300 56 
301 56 
302 56 
303 57 
304 57 
305 57 
306 57 
307 57 
308 58 
309 58 
310 58 
311 58 
312 59 
313 59 
314 59 
315 59 
316 59 
317 60 
318 60 
319 60 
320 60 
321 60 
322 61 
323 61 
324 61 
325 61 
326 62 
327 62 
328 62 
329 62 
330 62 
331 63 
332 63 
333 63 
334 63 
335 64 
336 64 
337 64 
338 64 
339 65 
340 65 
341 65 
342 65 
343 65 
344 66 
345 66 
346 66 
347 66 
348 67 
349 67 
350 67 
351 67 
352 67 
353 68 
354 68 
355 68 
356 68 
357 69 
358 69 
359 69 
360 69 
361 70 
362 70 
363 70 
364 70 
365 71 
366 71 
367 71 
368 71 
369 71 
370 72 
371 72 
372 72 
373 72 
374 73 
375 73 
376 73 
377 73 
378 74 
379 74 
380 74 
381 74 
382 75 
383 75 
384 75 
385 75 
386 75 
387 76 
388 76 
389 76 
390 76 
391 77 
392 77 
393 77 
394 77 
395 78 
396 78 
397 78 
398 78 
399 79 
400 79 
401 79 
402 79 
403 80 
404 80 
405 80 
406 80 
407 81 
408 81 
409 81 
410 81 
411 82 
412 82 
413 82 
414 82 
415 83 
416 83 
417 83 
418 83 
419 84 
420 84 
421 84 
422 84 
423 85 
424 85 
425 85 
426 85 
427 86 
428 86 
429 86 
430 86 
431 87 
432 87 
433 87 
434 87 
435 88 
436 88 
437 88 
438 88 
439 89 
440 89 
441 89 
442 89 
443 90 
444 90 
445 90 
446 90 
447 91 
448 91 
449 91 
450 91 
451 92 
452 92 
453 92 
454 92 
455 93 
456 93 
457 93 
458 93 
459 94 
460 94 
461 94 
462 95 
463 95 
464 95 
465 95 
466 96 
467 96 
468 96 
469 96 
470 97 
471 97 
472 97 
473 97 
474 98 
475 98 
476 98 
477 99 
478 99 
479 99 
480 99 
481 100 
482 100 
483 100 
484 100 
485 101 
486 101 
487 101 
488 101 
489 102 
490 102 
491 102 
492 103 
493 103 
494 103 
495 103 
496 104 
497 104 
498 104 
499 105 
500 105 
501 105 
502 105 
503 106 
504 106 
505 106 
506 106 
507 107 
508 107 
509 107 
510 108 
511 108 
512 108 
513 108 
514 109 
515 109 
516 109 
517 110 
518 110 
519 110 
520 110 
521 111 
522 111 
523 111 
524 112 
525 112 
526 112 
527 112 
528 113 
529 113 
530 113 
531 114 
532 114 
533 114 
534 114 
535 115 
536 115 
537 115 
538 116 
539 116 
540 116 
541 116 
542 117 
543 117 
544 117 
545 118 
546 118 
547 118 
548 118 
549 119 
550 119 
551 119 
552 120 
553 120 
554 120 
555 121 
556 121 
557 121 
558 121 
559 122 
560 122 
561 122 
562 123 
563 123 
564 123 
565 124 
566 124 
567 124 
568 124 
569 125 
570 125 
571 125 
572 126 
573 126 
574 126 
575 127 
576 127 
577 127 
578 127 
579 128 
580 128 
581 128 
582 129 
583 129 
584 129 
585 130 
586 130 
587 130 
588 131 
589 131 
590 131 
591 131 
592 132 
593 132 
594 132 
595 133 
596 133 
597 133 
598 134 
599 134 
600 134 
601 135 
602 135 
603 135 
604 136 
605 136 
606 136 
607 137 
608 137 
609 137 
610 137 
611 138 
612 138 
613 138 
614 139 
615 139 
616 139 
617 140 
618 140 
619 140 
620 141 
621 141 
622 141 
623 142 
624 142 
625 142 
626 143 
627 143 
628 143 
629 144 
630 144 
631 144 
632 145 
633 145 
634 145 
635 146 
636 146 
637 146 
638 147 
639 147 
640 147 
641 148 
642 148 
643 148 
644 149 
645 149 
646 149 
647 150 
648 150 
649 150 
650 151 
651 151 
652 151 
653 152 
654 152 
655 152 
656 153 
657 153 
658 153 
659 154 
660 154 
661 154 
662 155 
663 155 
664 155 
665 156 
666 156 
667 156 
668 157 
669 157 
670 157 
671 158 
672 158 
673 159 
674 159 
675 159 
676 160 
677 160 
678 160 
679 161 
680 161 
681 161 
682 162 
683 162 
684 162 
685 163 
686 163 
687 163 
688 164 
689 164 
690 165 
691 165 
692 165 
693 166 
694 166 
695 166 
696 167 
697 167 
698 167 
699 168 
700 168 
701 169 
702 169 
703 169 
704 170 
705 170 
706 170 
707 171 
708 171 
709 171 
710 172 
711 172 
712 173 
713 173 
714 173 
715 174 
716 174 
717 174 
718 175 
719 175 
720 176 
721 176 
722 176 
723 177 
724 177 
725 177 
726 178 
727 178 
728 179 
729 179 
730 179 
731 180 
732 180 
733 180 
734 181 
735 181 
736 182 
737 182 
738 182 
739 183 
740 183 
741 184 
742 184 
743 184 
744 185 
745 185 
746 186 
747 186 
748 186 
749 187 
750 187 
751 187 
752 188 
753 188 
754 189 
755 189 
756 189 
757 190 
758 190 
759 191 
760 191 
761 191 
762 192 
763 192 
764 193 
765 193 
766 193 
767 194 
768 194 
769 195 
770 195 
771 195 
772 196 
773 196 
774 197 
775 197 
776 197 
777 198 
778 198 
779 199 
780 199 
781 200 
782 200 
783 200 
784 201 
785 201 
786 202 
787 202 
788 202 
789 203 
790 203 
791 204 
792 204 
793 205 
794 205 
795 205 
796 206 
797 206 
798 207 
799 207 
800 207 
801 208 
802 208 
803 209 
804 209 
805 210 
806 210 
807 210 
808 211 
809 211 
810 212 
811 212 
812 213 
813 213 
814 214 
815 214 
816 214 
817 215 
818 215 
819 216 
820 216 
821 217 
822 217 
823 217 
824 218 
825 218 
826 219 
827 219 
828 220 
829 220 
830 221 
831 221 
832 221 
833 222 
834 222 
835 223 
836 223 
837 224 
838 224 
839 225 
840 225 
841 225 
842 226 
843 226 
844 227 
845 227 
846 228 
847 228 
848 229 
849 229 
850 230 
851 230 
852 231 
853 231 
854 231 
855 232 
856 232 
857 233 
858 233 
859 234 
860 234 
861 235 
862 235 
863 236 
864 236 
865 237 
866 237 
867 238 
868 238 
869 239 
870 239 
871 239 
872 240 
873 240 
874 241 
875 241 
876 242 
877 242 
878 243 
879 243 
880 244 
881 244 
882 245 
883 245 
884 246 
885 246 
886 247 
887 247 
888 248 
889 248 
890 249 
891 249 
892 250 
893 250 
894 251 
895 251 
896 252 
897 252 
898 253 
899 253 
900 254 
901 254 
902 255 
903 255 
904 256 
905 256 
906 257 
907 257 
908 258 
909 258 
910 259 
911 259 
912 260 
913 260 
914 261 
915 261 
916 262 
917 262 
918 263 
919 263 
920 264 
921 264 
922 265 
923 265 
924 266 
925 266 
926 267 
927 268 
928 268 
929 269 
930 269 
931 270 
932 270 
933 271 
934 271 
935 272 
936 272 
937 273 
938 273 
939 274 
940 274 
941 275 
942 276 
943 276 
944 277 
945 277 
946 278 
947 278 
948 279 
949 279 
950 280 
951 280 
952 281 
953 282 
954 282 
955 283 
956 283 
957 284 
958 284 
959 285 
960 285 
961 286 
962 287 
963 287 
964 288 
965 288 
966 289 
967 289 
968 290 
969 291 
970 291 
971 292 
972 292 
973 293 
974 293 
975 294 
976 295 
977 295 
978 296 
979 296 
980 297 
981 297 
982 298 
983 299 
984 299 
985 300 
986 300 
987 301 
988 301 
989 302 
990 303 
991 303 
992 304 
993 304 
994 305 
995 306 
996 306 
997 307 
998 307 
999 308
```

Comment: usually $\lceil \frac{n}{6} \rceil$ but not always

Comment: The rate of increase is greater toward the end. It might involve a quadratic, or maybe something else with $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ or some other "rounding" function.

Comment: Actually if we knew what the "integer factorization" problem was and what this list of data has to do with it, someone might recognize the function.

Comment: A nice question. I found no relevant sequence in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/). Your data grows slightly faster than $x\ln x$. Can you provide more data (for instance, up to $10^4$ or $10^5$) in order to estimate the asymptotics?